# Building a string representing 50+ ActiveDirectory options

Tags: c#, strings, enum, active-directory

I have a switch statement used to handle options that a user selected (stored in an array). The array is iterated through, and for each element (enum object) in the array, an appropriate action is performed. However, the enum has over 50 items, so the switch statement is very long.

The items are all necessary and related, so they cannot be moved or removed. They also each call a method or get a property of an object, so no dictionaries. Are there any other options to make this shorter?

```
public string GetUserAttributes(UserPrincipal user,
    ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute[] attributes)
{
    var userAsDirectoryEntry
        = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
    var userAttributes = string.Empty;
    foreach (ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute attribute in attributes)
    {
        switch (attribute)
        {
            case ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.AccountExpirationDate:
                userAttributes += AttributeToString(
                    user.AccountExpirationDate.ToString());
                break;
            case ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.AccountLockoutTime:
                userAttributes += AttributeToString(
                    user.AccountLockoutTime.ToString());
                break;
            case ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.Assistant:
                userAttributes += AttributeToString(
                    userAsDirectoryEntry.Properties[AttributeAssistant]
                    .Value.ToString());
                break;
            case ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.BadLogonCount:
                userAttributes += AttributeToString(
                    user.BadLogonCount.ToString());
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
    return userAttributes;
}
```

Comment: You can use `Reflection`: it can be an elegant solution and the whole `switch` disappears, but one condition is needed: the methods you call... are they all without input parameters (like property getters do)? If yes, I'll post a code snippet with the solution; otherwise, a switch/enum or a dictionary is necessary.

Comment: @MK87 Some of the methods do require parameters, and are not just property getters/setters.

Comment: Mhm... can you add a snippet of a method with parameters in your code? Where you get the parameters from?

Comment: @MK87 The only parameters are the `UserPrincipal` and the `DirectoryEntry`. They are in the form `GetSomeString(UserPrincipal user, DirectoryEntry userAsDirectoryEntry)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `switch-case`s into a dictionary to reduce the boilerplate `case` and `break`. The `foreach` and the string concatenation part can also be reduced with `string.Concat(...)` or `string.Join(delimiter, ...)`:

```
public string GetUserAttributes(UserPrincipal user, ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute[] attributes)
{
    var userAsDirectoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();

    var getters = new Dictionary<ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute, Func<object>>();
    getters[ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.AccountExpirationDate] = () => user.AccountExpirationDate;
    getters[ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.AccountLockoutTime] = () => user.AccountLockoutTime;
    getters[ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.Assistant] = () => userAsDirectoryEntry.Properties[AttributeAssistant].Value;
    getters[ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.BadLogonCount] = () => user.BadLogonCount;
    // ...

    // just concat them directly, like you are doing now
    return string.Concat(attributes.Select(attr => getters[attr]()));

    // or, you can separate them with a comma, or anything :
    return string.Join(", ", attributes
        .Select(attr => getters[attr]()));
}
```

---

You can also use the collection initializer for dictionary to cut down some letters :

```
var getters = new Dictionary<ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute, Func<object>>
{
    // C# 6
    [ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.AccountExpirationDate] = () => user.AccountExpirationDate,
    [ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.AccountLockoutTime] = () => user.AccountLockoutTime,

    // older version
    { ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.Assistant, () => userAsDirectoryEntry.Properties[AttributeAssistant].Value },
    { ActiveDirectoryUserAttribute.BadLogonCount, () => user.BadLogonCount },

    // ...
};
```

Personally I prefer the C# 6 collection initializer the most, second by the method shown in first snippet, and lastly the older initializer.

Comment: Just a note, the semicolon needs to go after the closing brace of the collection initializer, not after the open/close parentheses.

Comment: You can also omit the parent's empty constructor parentheses in collection/object initializers.

Comment: Ahh, Copy-paste programming! The source of all evil! A syntax error and 1 style problem in a single line...